# ServerSide Application for Linux Server

Tags: c, linux, netbeans

I am entirely new to Linux platform.I am working on a server Application in C Language for Amazon server which will simultaneously receive data from multiple sources.I am using NetBeans IDE for coding in C language.when i consuletd a Linux server expert he said that only files with .sh extension are executeable in Linux environment.While i checked the properties of my Netbeans output file in dist folder it was showing

```
 TYPE: executable (application/x-executable)
```

Will this file be able to execute on the Linux Server.

Comment: I believe, you can run your output file using `./<outputfilename>`

Comment: Also, you can always check the permission of a file (executable or not) by using `ls -l <filename>`.

Comment: @SouravGhosh it is showing following output
-rwxrwxr-x 1 simer simer 9288 May 22 11:24 socketserver

Comment: Anything that has its execute bit set is executable. Clearly your binary has its executable bit set, so the only reason it wouldn't run is because it is not within your default PATH. So just prepend the path to the binary to run it.

Comment: notice the `rwx` pattern, these pare permission bits (indicator) for that file. `r`--> `read`, `w`--> `write`, `x`--> `execute`. So, you can simply move to the directory where the file exists, and do a `./socketserver`